# Авторизация на сайте через requests python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, аутентификация

Я использую requests для получения информации из сайта:

```
datas = {'login': lst[0], 'password': lst[1]}
s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://elschool.ru/logon/index'
loging = s.post(url, data=datas)
url = 'https://elschool.ru/users/diaries/details?RooId=18&InstituteId=112&DepartmentId=115968&PupilId=141652&Year=2020&Week=40&log=False'
page = s.get(url, data=datas)
print(page.text)
```

Но при выводе информации я не авторизируюсь, и получить html код страницы мне нужной получить соответственно не могу. Но если я использую логин и пароль, которые сохранены в моем браузере, то все работает. Кто знает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ничего не понял. В чём тружность-то?

Comment: Авторизация не проходит, и меня перекидывает на страницу с повторной попыткой авторизации

Comment: Браузер после логина выставляет cookies со специальным ключом авторизации. cookies отправляются всякий раз с каждым запросом. Доводилось об этом слышать?

Comment: Нет. А как мне использовать эти куки для входа?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554771/how-to-use-cookies-in-python-requests

Comment: Но я ведь и так использую Session. В ней и должны сохранятся все cookies. Или нет?

Comment: Да, не обратил внимание, очень странно. А `status_code` у POST-запроса 200? На промежуточных точках никаких ошибок?

Comment: Да, 200. Очень странно

Comment: Как будто все равно не сохраняются куки

Comment: Но пароли точно верные

Comment: Сохраняются или нет - это легко проверить https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.cookies

Comment: Их нет! Вот список s.cookies.items(): `[('JWToken', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJJZCI6IjE0MTc5NiIsIk11c3RDaGFuZ2VQYXNzd29yZCI6IkZhbHNlIiwicm9sZSI6IjgsRGVwYXJ0bWVudCwsMTgsMTEyLDExNTk2OCwiLCJFU0lBTG9nb24iOiJGYWxzZSIsIm5iZiI6MTYwMTMxOTYwMCwiZXhwIjoxNjAxOTI0NDAwLCJpYXQiOjE2MDEzOTEyNjEsImlzcyI6IjEwLjYyLjM0LjE2IiwiYXVkIjoiaXQuYnJzYy5ydSJ9.Kw_v62BOuRIUf0yTc6sFdbbtNHYJjz3sbbRG3xBIyL8')]`

Comment: В чем тогда проблема?

Comment: А может ли быть такое, что авторизация хранится не в cookies? Есть ли другие варианты? И если да, то как с ними бороться?

Comment: @Oopsss jwt это авторизация и она в куках

Answer (score 0):

Jwt авторизация обычно работает так. Через куку страничка получает jwt token и выствляет его в хидер Authorization: Bearer xxxx.yyyy.zzzz

Comment: А как я могу воспользоваться этим токеном? Чтобы я зашёл на сайт

Comment: Почему меня все таки не авторизирует на сайте?